# Change color back after setState

Tags: flutter

I have column of InkWells. When a button is pressed, it changes color to red from white. The problem is, when another button is pressed, the previous button doesn't change back to white.

How can I solve this?

```
class NavigationButton extends StatefulWidget {

  const NavigationButton({
    Key key,
    this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _NavigationButtonState createState() => _NavigationButtonState();
}

class _NavigationButtonState extends State<NavigationButton> {

  Color _color = Colors.white;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        InkWell(
          highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              widget.title,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 25)
            )
          ),
          onTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _color = Colors.red;
            });
          }
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Container(
          width: 10,
          height: 10,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: _color, shape: BoxShape.circle)
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

The menu wuth navigation buttons:

```
      child: Container(
        height: 205,
        width: 210,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            for (int index = 0; index < _sectionsName.length; index++)
            NavigationButton(title: _sectionsName[index], index: index)
          ]
        )
      )
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: You want to change the color from white to red on button tap and then again to white on tapping another button or automatically after few milliseconds/seconds to white

Comment: And add the code for your second button as well

Comment: It's the same button used while creating a list of buttons in another screen.
And yes, it should change to white again when the button is tapped.

Answer (score 0):

can be solved by taking a boolean variable isSeleted;

For the current situation you will have to take bool in the widget where you have defined the  NavigationButton List and wrap navigationButton with gesturedetector.

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NavigationButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final buttonColor;
  final textColor;
  final String title;

  const NavigationButton({
    Key key,
    this.title,
    this.buttonColor,
    this.textColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NavigationButtonState createState() => _NavigationButtonState();
}

class _NavigationButtonState extends State<NavigationButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: widget.buttonColor,
          ),
          child: Container(
            child: Text(
              widget.title,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: widget.textColor,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  // List isSelected = [];
  Map _sectionsName = {"one ": false, "two": false};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 205,
        width: 210,
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
        child: ListView(
          children: _sectionsName.keys
              .map<Widget>((item) => GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      _sectionsName.forEach((key, value) {
                        if (key == item) {
                          setState(() {
                            _sectionsName[key] = true;
                          });
                        }else{
                          _sectionsName[key] = false;
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: NavigationButton(
                      title: item,
                      buttonColor: _sectionsName[item] == true
                          ? Colors.red
                          : Colors.white,
                      textColor: _sectionsName[item] == true
                          ? Colors.white
                          : Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have edited the code above pls take a look

Comment: I really appreciate your help. But the code doesn't work. Now the menu is always black text with white circles.

Comment: sorry for that , the new above code surely works ... it changes color when tapped